# Variations of Assouad’s lemma

Tags: covariance-matrix, asymptotics

I'm reading the paper [Optimal Rates of Convergence for Sparse Covariance Matrix Estimation](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~tcai/paper/Sparse-Covariance-Matrix.pdf) by T. Cai and H. Zhou.

They refer to a specific version of Assouad's Lemma (see lemma 2, p. 6 of the linked paper), which differs from the one I've found in Yu [1] and Le Cam [2]. I've also ordered van der Vaart [3], but it has yet to arrive.

Can do you know of a resource that contains a proof of the version Cai states? Or can you give a proof?

I'm especially interested because I'm having trouble with their proof of lemma 3 (p. 7 of linked paper, proof p. 21) and the lemmas seem very related. Specifically, I don't understand how the use of

$\hat{\theta} = \mbox{argmin}_{\theta \in \Theta} d(T,\psi (\theta))$

in eq. (37) is meaningful as $T$ is a random variable.

[1] B. Yu (1997). Assouad, Fano, and Le Cam. Festschrift for Lucien Le Cam. D. Pollard, E. Torgersen, and G. Yang (eds), pp. 423-435, Springer-Verlag.

[2] Le Cam, L. (1986). Asymptotic Methods in Statistical Decision Theory. SpringerVerlag, New York.

[3] van der Vaart, A.W. (1998). Asymptotic Statistics. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge.

Comment: The form of Assouad's lemme given in the paper as Lemma 2 is identical to that given in van der Vaart on page 347. You might consider including the lemmas you are interested in directly in the question to make it more self-contained.

Comment: @cardinal Thanks, that's really all I wanted to know for now. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Hopefully this will help me understand the Cai/Zhou proof.